# how to use file protocol open my documents

Tags: file

```
 popToastControl.Payload =
            $@"
            <toast activationType='protocol' launch='file:///C|/My Documents/'>
                <visual>
                    <binding template='ToastGeneric'>
                        <text>Click to launch Bing Maps</text>
                        <text>Searches for ""1 Microsoft Way, 98052""</text>
                    </binding>
                </visual>
            </toast>";
```

I cannot open my documents through `file protocol(file:///...)`

I tried like this: `file:///%USERPROFILE%\My Documents`
 =>did not work

nor did this way: `file:///%My Documents%`

it only worked as this way :`file:///C:\Users\Michael-DEV\Documents`

Please get me off this trouble, much thanks!

Comment: This issue occured when I tried to skip to my documents by click a toast message in UWP develepment

Comment: I learned from this sample.
...\Windows-universal-samples-master\Samples\Notifications\cs
  [1]: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples